# Chinese traditional singing

Tags: difference, pronunciation

To my American ears, traditional high pitched Chinese singing sounds strange. Also, in the movie 活着 when the protagonist Fugui sings in his puppet troupe he sounds so weird/funny to me, but it doesn't seem like his audience in the film thinks it sounds weird. Do native Chinese people view traditional singing as beautiful, such as the high pitched opera songs? Do they think some American/European music like Italian opera or others sound strange, while Americans/Europeans think it sounds beautiful? If so, what would be an example?

Comment: This is basically an opinion based question, which is unfortunately not encouraged here. [see rules](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do native Chinese people view traditional singing as beautiful, such
>   as the high pitched opera songs?

It's beautiful, not it's hard to be popular. The young generation is not favoring opera songs, but they might love the songs that perform opera songs in a modern/popular way.

> Do they think some American/European music like Italian opera or
>   others sound strange, while Americans/Europeans think it sounds
>   beautiful? If so, what would be an example?

Not strange if the ACG use opera as BGM. And the fan of opera/classical song is not large. Most of the people love listening to these songs(mostly edited to 5,6 minutes version) from radio, but they might not go to a theater to listen to hour-long opera. Although the number of the audience is increasing, but it's still too small to call a mainstream culture.

Claims: 26-year-old Native Chinese, Now living in America.

Comment: What are ACG and BGM?

Comment: @艾锐心 ACG: anime-comics and games. BGM: background music

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't seem like his audience in the film thinks it sounds weird.

This is probably because we live in this culture and are used to such kinds of music.

In addition, Chinese opera is more focused on storytelling and actors performance than being a beautiful piece of music for everyone to enjoy.

If you are looking for some beautiful traditional Chinese music, here are some examples:
[无锡景](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMfBX2g9pyo) or [秦淮景](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ai6fBVjMJB0)
, [诗经](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7D7opLqC5g) and [越人歌](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2c4somJbLg).

诗经 and 越人歌 are probably modern compositions but they are close to the music style in [Spring and Autumn period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) and [Warring States period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)

Comment: > "诗经 and 越人歌 are probably modern compositions but they are close to the music style in Spring and Autumn period and Warring States period." They are nothing like the music styles of those periods, and are completely made up, just FYI.